# Many to one where the one can be one of two different fields

Tags: postgresql, select, relationship

I've had a look at similar posts on one to many and many to one relationships but I just can't find what I'm looking for.  I have 2 tables.  The first (vm) contains details of virtual machines.  The vms are clustered in pairs and the second table (cluster) has details of the cluster.  The set up is as follows:

```
vm table                       cluster table
    vmId                           clusterId
    ipaddress                      primaryId
    macaddress                     secondaryId
```

The relationship is that the vm.vmId can be a match to either cluster.primaryId or cluster.secondaryId.  With only an ipaddress I want to be able to get the full cluster details as follows:

```
clusterid   vmId    ipaddress   macaddress
c1          v1      10.0.10.10  AA:BB:CC:DD:10:11
C1          v2      10.0.10.11  AA:BB:CC:DD:10:12
```

and that's my problem.  With just the ipaddress I can find the vmId and with that I can get the cluster, but I can't then work out how to use the non matching id in the cluster table to get the other vm details.  I've tried variables and unions etc., but I must be doing something wrong because I keep coming up blank.  I'm looking for a single select statement that will provide the required result.  Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your help I did finally manage to get the answer I was looking for.  With a little modification of your suggestions I finally came up with this.

```
with clusters as (
  select clusterId
  from cluster
  where exists (
    select 1
    from vm 
    where
      (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId or vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId) and 
      wm.ipaddress = '10.0.10.10'))
select clusterId, vmId, ipaddress, macaddress
from vm
join cluster on (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId or vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId)
where cluster.clusterId = (select * from clusters)
```

Produced exactly the result I was looking for.  Thanks everyone for your assistence.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for, but realize that the vmIds will appear twice, once under the primary cluster, and another under the secondary cluster.

```
SELECT clusterid, vmId, ipaddress, macaddress
FROM vm
JOIN cluster
  ON vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId
UNION ALL
SELECT clusterid, vmId, ipaddress, macaddress
FROM vm
JOIN cluster
  ON vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId
```

The above can be reduced to:

```
SELECT clusterid, vmId, ipaddress, macaddress
FROM vm
JOIN cluster
  ON (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId OR vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId)
```

If you want to filter the result:

```
SELECT clusterid, vmId, ipaddress, macaddress
FROM vm
JOIN cluster
  ON (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId OR vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId)
WHERE ipaddress = '10.0.10.10'
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing here.  There's no 'where' clause.  Depending on which of the ip addresses I'm starting out with, there should be a "where ipaddress='10.0.10.10' " or "where ipaddress='10.0.10.11'" somewhere.. That's the bit that's got me flustered. I only want the cluster details for the pair where one of the ip addresses matches the one I've already got.

Comment: @JS I added the reduction to a compound conditional in the join, and added a where clause.

Comment: Sadly this is still only giving me the details for the ipaddress I already have but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

First find the cluster(s) with given IP:

```
select *
from cluster
where exists (
    select 1
    from vm
    where
        (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId or vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId) and 
        wm.ipaddress = '127.0.0.1');
```

Then join this with `vm` table in the same way:

```
with clusters as (
    select *
    from cluster
    where exists (
        select 1
        from vm
        where
            (vm.vmId = cluster.primaryId or vm.vmId = cluster.secondaryId) and 
            wm.ipaddress = '127.0.0.1'))
select *
from clusters join vm on (vm.vmId = clusters.primaryId or vm.vmId = clusters.secondaryId);
```

Comment: The first option only gives me results for the ipdaddress I already have. So that's only half the answer.
The second throws a an error: missing from-clause entry for table cluster.

Comment: @JS The second query should not throws such error because the subquery where `cluster` used just copy-pasted from the first one. In any case I can not debug it for you because I have no access to your DB.

Comment: No problem Abelisto.  I did manage to resolve that 'missing from-clause' issue with the addition of the select in the final comparison.  Thus

"where cluster.clusterId = (select * from clusters)"